# ASIHTTPREQUEST not working as expected in iOS 8.3

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios11, asihttprequest

I have used asihttprequest classes in my app for calling web-api.

But now it's not working in iOS 8.3 as well as in iOS 11+ and already full app was developed so can't change whole `asihttprequest` to `afnetworking` so I need some solution in `asihttprequest` only.

I want to add that when I am calling api using `startAsynchronous` it's not working but when I am using `startSynchronous` it's working fine but for a while it freezes the app.

Once request sent it's not come back with any response not failed or success.

I am using ASIFormDataRequest to call api like this.

```
 NSString *stringurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kBaseUrl,kForgotPasswordAPI];
    NSString * encodedUrl = [stringurl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl];
    requestForgotPassword = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [requestForgotPassword setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [requestForgotPassword setPostValue:@"mobile" forKey:@"environment"];
    [requestForgotPassword setPostValue:txtEmailAddress.text forKey:@"email_address"];
    [requestForgotPassword setTimeOutSeconds:60];
    [requestForgotPassword setDelegate:self];
    [requestForgotPassword startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: omg, ASIHTTPRequest has been abandoned many years ago. You shouldn't have used it.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha ya i know but it's working fine in ios 10 and haven't checked in ios 8.3 is there any solution for it.

Comment: Please add some code how you use it and explain what is not working.

Comment: @Koen please see i have added code how i am calling webservice using  ASIFormDataRequest.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/07/19/asynchronous-synchronous-requests-effortless-networking-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the answer as i describe my problem i am facing problem while calling web-Api using ASIHTTPREQUEST.

Now what i have done to solve that issue is i have change api calling time like first i am calling api in viewDidLoad() but now i have calling api in viewDidAppear() and it's working fine for me.

If anyone else facing same problem please try this solution and please don't use this ASIHTTPREQUEST class in next project.

Thank you.